# python 2.3 how to run a piped command

Tags: python, python-2.3

I want to run a command like this

```
grep -w 1 pattern <(tail -f mylogfile.log)
```

basically from a python script i want to monitor a log file for a specific string and continue with the python script as soon as i found that.
I am using `os.system()`, but that is hanging. The same command in bash works good.

I have a very old version of python (v2.3) and so don't have sub-process module.

do we have a way to acheive this

Comment: You could try the `commands` module, but at least one person should give to simple answer -- upgrade to a newer version of python ;)

Comment: presumably he has the same problem upgrading python as he does pulling [`subprocess.py` from SVN](http://svn.python.org/view/%2acheckout%2a/python/tags/r255/Lib/subprocess.py)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In Python 2.3, you need to use [`subprocess` from SVN](http://svn.python.org/view/%2acheckout%2a/python/tags/r255/Lib/subprocess.py)

```
import subprocess
import shlex
subprocess.call(shlex.split("/bin/bash -c 'grep -w 1 pattern <(tail -f mylogfile.log)'"))
```

To be explicit, you need to install it from the SVN link above.

You need to call this with `/bin/bash -c` due to the shell redirection you're using

---

**EDIT**

If you want to solve this with `os.system()`, just wrap the command in `/bin/bash -c` since you're using shell redirection...

```
os.system("/bin/bash -c 'grep -w 1 pattern <(tail -f mylogfile.log)'")
```

Comment: again, i don't have subprocess and can't download any new modules in my current enviroment :-(

Comment: Not being able to download is new information, that would have been nice to know... although I wonder how hard it is to copy `subprocess.py` into a file in `vi` since you're presumably accessing via `ssh`

Answer (score 0):

First of all, the command i think you should be using is `grep -w -m 1 'pattern' <(tail -f in)`

For executing commands in python, use the Popen constructor from the subprocess module. Read more at
http://docs.python.org/library/subprocess.html

Answer (score -1):

If I understand correctly, you want to send the output to python like this -

```
tail -f mylogfile.log | grep -w 1 pattern | python yourscript.py
```

i.e., read all updates to the log file, and send matching lines to your script.

To read from standard input, you can use the file-like object: sys.stdin.

So your script would look like

```
import sys

for line in sys.stdin.readlines():
    #process each line here.
```